# PMF and CDF from a piecewise function in R

Tags: r, probability, probability-density, piecewise, probability-distribution

Given

```r
p <- function(x) {
  if (x == -4) {
    0.1
  } else if (x == -1) {
    0.2
  } else if (x == 1) {
    0.6
  } else if (x == 2) {
    0.1
  } else {
    0
  }
}
```

How would I plot the PMF and CDF. No distribution is specified so I cant use the build in commands. What would be the best way to plot these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

If piece-wise CDF is needed, you can try define `cdf` function

```
cdf <- function(x) {
    ifelse(
        x <= -4,
        0,
        ifelse(
            x <= -1,
            0.1,
            ifelse(
                x <= 1,
                0.3,
                ifelse(
                    x < 2,
                    0.9,
                    1
                )
            )
        )
    )
}
```

and then run

```
curve(cdf, -5, 5, n = 1e3 + 1)
```

[image]

---

## Previous

Try this for PMF

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(-4, -1, 1, 2), p = c(.1, .2, .6, .1))
plot(df, type = "l")
points(df)
```

[image]

---

For CDF, you can try a similar one

```
plot(df_cdf <- transform(df, p = cumsum(p)), type = "l")
points(df_cdf)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to connect the dots? or make a curve.

Comment: @mathstudent23 Use `type =  "l"`

Comment: Okay would a cdf be possible with this method? And would you be able to draw "lines" from the given x up to its probability?

Comment: As points are connected by lines, can we plot stepwise function for the cdf using the given pmf ? @ThomaslsCoding

Comment: @ankit see my update

Answer (score 1):

Easy and simple solution (assuming `p` to be defined as in the question):

```r
### support
x <- seq(-4, 2, 1)
### PDF
plot(x, sapply(x, p), ylab = "PDF")
### CDF
plot(x, cumsum(sapply(x, p)), ylab = "CDF")
```

Comment: 1 question though. Why do we not write all the x's in the seq? i.e (-4, -1, 0, 1, 2)

Comment: You can do that, just specify `x = c(-4, -1, 0, 1, 2)`.

Comment: As only points are showing for the cdf, can we plot stepwise function for the cdf using the given pmf ? @Lennart

Comment: For steps, you can add the `type = "s"` or `type = "S"` argument to the `plot()` function.